# ensure that code in componentDidMount is executed when a component is re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been debugging my react web app for a while now trying to figure out why my state wasn't showing an update in one of my components.

I finally realized that I am using axios like this in my component:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`/api/dungeon_generation/texture-files/${this.props.genId}/files`)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ files: response.data })
            console.log("axios get: ", this.state.files);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

So when I reload that component, componentDidMount is not getting called again.

How can I change it so that the axios.get method is ran both when the component is first loaded and when I need to update the state and reload it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by reload? and how you are doing that.

Comment: @MayankShukla I mean if I need to re-render that particular component again, I've noticed that componentDidMount doesn't run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the logic in a separate method, and call that both in `componentDidMount` and in `componentDidUpdate` when your `genId` prop changes.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(this.props.genId);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.genId !== prevProps.genId) {
      this.fetchData(this.props.genId);
    }
  }

  fetchData = (genId) => {
    axios.get(`/api/dungeon_generation/texture-files/${genId}/files`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ files: response.data })
        console.log("axios get: ", this.state.files);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `componentDidMount` gets called only once when the component is first mounted in `DOM`.
- When the component gets re-rendered, `componentDidUpdate` gets called.

`componentDidUpdate` does not get called for the initial render. So, use both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` if it is some sort of post-render action.

Answer (score 1):

You can do your API call in both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

See documentation for [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) here.